# How do you add authentication to Web API?

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I read documentation but there is no clear example of app implementing either JWT or Cookies I tried custom approach from tutorial but it didn't work. Im pretty lost here I have Web API that is for a shop I have created users and hash the password them in database but I don't know how to implement authentication and authorisation the reason is whenever I generate project in MVC its always added by default but here it wasn't and I'm pretty lost. If anyone can help me out thanks.

Here is start up:

```
public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddDbContext<TechStoreDbContext>();

            services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            services.AddAuthentication();

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "TechStore.Api", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services.AddDataProtection();

            services.AddScoped<IRepository<Product>, ProductRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IRepository<User>, UserRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IRepository<Cart>, CartRepository>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "TechStore.Api v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is User class:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Adress { get; set; }

        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public Cart Cart { get; set; }

        public int CartId { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is Register controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserModel>> Post(UserModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Creating cart for user and adding to database...");

                var cartCreated = await _cartRepository.Add(new Cart());
                model.CartId = cartCreated.Id;

                var passwordHash = BC.HashPassword(model.Password);
                model.Password = passwordHash;

                var modelToUser = _mapper.Map<User>(model);

                _logger.LogInformation("Adding user to database...");

                var user = await _userRepository.Add(modelToUser);

                return _mapper.Map<UserModel>(modelToUser);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.Message);

                if (_webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex);
                }

                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Database failure");
            }
            
        }
```

Now how do I implement login and how do authorise controllers which should be for admins. I know the attribute but I don't know how to implement it in Web API?

Comment: all depends what you are are authing with, there is tons of examples on the net, this question is a bit open ended

Comment: I try to do it with JWT or Cookie. I searched a lot and there are small snippets of code I want to know how it fits in application in startup config and controllers.

Comment: @Aniki Check this https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2017/09/06/secure-web-api-in-asp-net-core/